# php extract chinese traditional characters

Tags: php, encoding

```
$str = "I want to eat我要吃飯 , you?你呢?";
```

I want output :

```
array(
0 => I,
1 => want, 
2 => to, 
3 => eat, 
4 => 我, 
5 => 要, 
6 => 吃,
...  ...
);
```

I tried :

## 1

```
function mb_str_split($str, $length = 1) {
  if ($length < 1) return FALSE;

  $result = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i += $length) {
    $result[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $length);
  }

  return $result;
}
var_dump(mb_str_split($str, 3));
```

Above method only works if all string is chinese traditional.

## 2

```
preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $str, $matches);
```

Above method only return first string of chinese, which is 我要吃飯. How to get all (我要吃飯, 你呢) ?

All uses UTF8.　
How to achieve my desired output ?

Comment: Are 我要吃飯 and 你呢 supposed to be seen as more than two words (more than two distinct values of your output array)?

If so, how many words would you like to find in your output array?

Comment: Two words (我要吃飯 + 你呢) acceptable. Six words (我,要,吃,飯,你,呢) also acceptable. The major point is I need to extract ALL the chinese words from the string. And will be perfect if I can also get the normal words also like (I, want, to, eat ..). I just can't separate the chinese and english words now.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

From this code excerpt, you might "just" need to figure how to preserve the English words:

```
<?php

$words = "I want to eat我要吃飯 , you ? 你呢 ?";
$tokens = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $words);
print_r($tokens);

//  Array
// (
//     [0] => I
//     [1] => w
//     [2] => a
//     [3] => n
//     [4] => t
//     [5] => t
//     [6] => o
//     [7] => e
//     [8] => a
//     [9] => t
//     [10] => 我
//     [11] => 要
//     [12] => 吃
//     [13] => 飯
//     [14] => ,
//     [15] => y
//     [16] => o
//     [17] => u
//     [18] => ?
//     [19] => 你
//     [20] => 呢
//     [21] => ?
// )
```

*EDIT*

Would this solution be satisfying enough?

```
$words = explode(' ', "I want to eat 我要吃飯 , you ? 你呢 ?");
$output = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $tokens = mb_split('\s', $word, 1);
    $output = array_merge($output, $tokens);
}

print_r($output);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => I
//     [1] => want
//     [2] => to
//     [3] => eat
//     [4] => 我要吃飯
//     [5] => ,
//     [6] => you
//     [7] => ?
//     [8] => 你呢
//     [9] => ?
// )
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad example. The str sometimes is attached like this : 'I want to eat我要吃飯'. So I can't use a whitespace character as separator. I update my question.

Comment: I updated last time, the str now is "I want to eat我要吃飯". With your above method, I get "eat我要吃飯". The problem is how to separate "eat" and "我要吃飯".